# Large file uploads from React to Google Storage architecture

Tags: reactjs, file-upload

I am working on the client side of an application that involves uploading multiple large files (over 2gb) to Google Cloud Storage, and I had a few questions about how to approach this.

1.Does GCS support uploads directly from client side or do I upload it to our backend and the backend deals with it?

2.Should I upload the files one by one or all together?

3.Should I divide files into chunks?

4.Do I send them over HTTP?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Running into the same situation and unable to find much information on how to approach.